# Listing keys of datetype which has a string date in a list of dicts python

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, dictionary

I am new to python. I have a list of dicts. The Values in the dicts are `String` and `Int`. 
Here, the list of dicts,

```
a = [{ 'Item Type': 'Household', 'Sales Channel': 'Offline', 'Order Date': '2016-05-29','Ship Date': '2016-06-25 22:59:23', 'Units Sold': 1485 },{ 'Item Type': 'Fruits', 'Sales Channel': 'Offline', 'Order Date': '2016-11-11',  'Ship Date': '2016-11-20 22:59:23', 'Units Sold': 6267 }]
```

I have datetime in the key `Ship Date` and `Order Date` which is in the form of string. I am gathering the type of fields in the Dict. I have taken `int fields` to `int type` and `all fields` to `all types`. But I don't know how to get the `date field` to the `date type`. Help me with some solutions.

Here's the Code, I wrote,

```
from datetime import datetime
a = [{ 'Item Type': 'Household', 'Sales Channel': 'Offline', 'Order Date': '2016-05-29','Ship Date': '2016-06-25 22:59:23', 'Units Sold': 1485 },{ 'Item Type': 'Fruits', 'Sales Channel': 'Offline', 'Order Date': '2016-11-11',  'Ship Date': '2016-11-20 22:59:23', 'Units Sold': 6267 }]

full_type_data = {}; int_type = []; all_type = []; date_type = []
for i in a:
    for j in i:
        if type(i[j]) == type(1) or type(i[j]) == type(1.1) :
            if j not in int_type: int_type.append(j)
        elif j not in all_type: all_type.append(j)
full_type_data = {"all_type":all_type, "int_type":int_type}
print("full_type_data",full_type_data)
```

Output Got:

```
full_type_data {'all_type': ['Item Type', 'Sales Channel', 'Order Date', 'Ship Date'], 'int_type': ['Units Sold', 'Rating']}
```

Required Output:

```
full_type_data {'all_type': ['Item Type', 'Sales Channel', 'Order Date', 'Ship Date'], 'int_type': ['Units Sold', 'Rating'], 'date_type': ['Order Date', 'Ship Date']}
```

Comment: will the date always be in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format?

Comment: @Joshi R, No. It can be any other formats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use dateutil.parser to check if a string is date.

```
from dateutil.parser
import parse
def is_datetime(string, fuzzy = False):
  try:
      parse(string, fuzzy = fuzzy)
      return True

  except ValueError:
      return False
```

then use this function in your code if-else block. Modified your code below

```
from datetime import datetime
a = [{
    'Item Type': 'Household',
    'Sales Channel': 'Offline',
    'Order Date': '2016-05-29',
    'Ship Date': '2016-06-25 22:59:23',
    'Units Sold': 1485,
    }, {
    'Item Type': 'Fruits',
    'Sales Channel': 'Offline',
    'Order Date': '2016-11-11',
    'Ship Date': '2016-11-20 22:59:23',
    'Units Sold': 6267,
    }]

full_type_data = {}
int_type = []
all_type = []
date_type = []

for i in a:
    for j in i:
        if type(i[j]) == type(1) or type(i[j]) == type(1.1):
            if j not in int_type:
                int_type.append(j)
        elif is_datetime(i[j]):
            if j not in date_type:
                date_type.append(j)
        elif j not in all_type:
            all_type.append(j)
full_type_data = {'all_type': all_type, 'int_type': int_type,
                  'date_type': date_type}
print ('full_type_data', full_type_data)
```

Hope this will work.

Answer (score 2):

A pythonic way to check for types is to just try a cast and catch the error.

```
try:
  cast = int(string_value)
except ValueError:
  pass # string_value was no int
else:
  do_something() # string value was an int
```

You can do the same with date and datetime:

```
from datetime import datetime

try:
  cast = datetime.fromisoformat(string_value)
except ValueError:
  pass # string_value was no datetime
else:
  do_something() # string value was a datetime
```

Wrap this in functions and you can make your code very clean:

```
def is_datetime(value):
  try:
    datetime.fromisoformat(string_value)
  except ValueError:
    return False
  else:
    return True
```

Comment: its not guaranteed to be isoformat ... `python-dateutil` would probably be better to use i think (although he never said he needed them as datetimes so it might be suffiecient `if "Date" in key`

Comment: The example timestamps in the question are both successfully parsed by `fromisoformat`. Of course, for the date, `datetime.date` would have to be used.

Comment: look at the comments on OP (+1 all the same since i think this answer is really steering him right)